# All list items change to appended item, in Python

Tags: python, list, file, object, datatable

I am using Python 2.7, using only standard modules.

I have a huge data file that contains a bunch of information about car events. I am trying to copy the data about an individual car event type (e.g. Acceleration) and write it to separate file. My current approach stores the data in a table --I used lists within lists-- before I write it to the separate file (See Example Table below).

```
Event Type | Data Location Start | Data Location End 
--------------------------------------------
Accelerate | 99                  | 181
Break      | 182                 | 263 
Horn       | 264                 | 351
Accelerate | 352                 | 434
...and so on

The table above in Python would be:

event_list = [['Accelerate', 99, 181], 
              ['Break', 182, 263], 
              ['Horn', 264, 351],
              ['Accelerate', 352, 434]]
```

**Issue:** Every time I append a row, all other rows change to that appended row. I have provided my code and the console output below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
""" File Description """

import os

def main():
    """ Organize Car Data Into New File """

    event_list = []             # This is the entire table
    first_event = True          # This is a flag
    single_event = [-1, -1, -1] # This is a single row in the table
                                # [Event Name, Code Line Start, Code Line End]

    with open('C:/car_event_data.dat', 'rb') as f:
        line = '-1'

        while line != '':                           # If line = '' then it is EOF
            line = f.readline()
            if line[0:6] == 'Event:':
                if first_event == False:            
                    single_event[2] = f.tell() - 1  # Code Line End
                    event_list.append(single_event) # Completed row
                    print(event_list)
                end = line.find('\x03', 6)          # Find the end location of Event Type
                single_event[0] = line[6:end]       # Event Type
                single_event[1] = f.tell()          # Code Line Start
                first_event = False

        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)                      # Put pointer at EOF
        single_event[2] = f.tell()
        event_list.append(single_event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code above generates the following output:

```
[['Accelerate', 99, 181]]
[['Break', 182, 263], ['Break', 182, 263]]
[['Horn', 264, 351], ['Horn', 264, 351], ['Horn', 264, 351]]
... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List objects are passed by reference in Python. The reason the previously appended elements are mutating to the current row is because they all point to the same list, single_event.

A simple

```
single_event = list(range(3))
```

after each append operation should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixes the problem

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer (the green tick mark) as well, helps with the rep :)